# Why does the method run without an item being selected?

Tags: android, android-spinner

When the fragment is opened i.e the `onCreateView` method is called the `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener())` is called even though no item has been selected yet.

Why is this and how would it be possible to change the code to make it so that the method is only called when an item is selected?

here is the code:

```
package com.petroc.nationaldiploma;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class AddGradesFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private GradesDataSource datasource;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Spinner spinner;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_grades, container,
            false);

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Pass");
    list.add("Merit");
    list.add("Distinction");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    // EditText editText = (EditText)
    // view.findViewById(R.id.editModuleText1);

    return view;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set data into the spinner using list object and adapter it was select the default value as 0 on setting time so that's why you getting selected